# How do I create an ASP.NET Core (6/7) Web AP controller to receive a model with a variable length list of a base type, like strings or decimals?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, .net-7.0

I have this API exposed using Swagger and my unit tests works with the request. It takes a variable number of params in the constructor to initialize the request and then I want to post it to the API.

But already in Swagger it goes wrong. I cannot figure out what format to make the JSON to be able to post it in a format that my controller will accept.

Is this approach not possible or what is it that I am missing?

Comment: Could you please share some codes about which class you used to send to the controller and which request you posted in the swagger is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your variable length value as a `List<T>` like this:

```cs
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public OkResult Post(MyRequest request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public List<string> Names { get; set; }

    public List<decimal> Grades { get; set; }
}
```

And the JSON for this request would look like this:

```json
{
  "names": [
    "name1",
    "name2"
  ],
  "grades": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

Comment: sorry, its more like Param as a variable list of what can be used in the query, if I have the request defined, I also know which variables could be defined - and yes - this would be a way to solve it, but not what I am trying to achive